# Double quotes inside a value of a json string in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to be able to extract the value from a json string column in bigquery
For instance,

`SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR('{"bbb":"\"aaa\""}', '$.bbb') as hello`

Is that possible to run that query and get "aaa"? What do i need to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in that pasted code is the escaping of the quotes.

Try either of these, and you'll get the desired results:

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(r'{"bbb":"\"aaa\""}', '$.bbb') as hello
```

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR('{"bbb":"\\"aaa\\""}', '$.bbb') as hello
```